# its possible create in linux a virtual wifi network that limit my original network to the 50% of speed?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking

My original network has a 400 kb/s download speed and 100 kb/s upload speed.

I need to create a virtual network of 200 kb/s download speed and 50 kb/s upload speed.

How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What research have you done so far? Have you tried anything? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try Wonder Shaper 1.4.  Wonder Shaper is a script that allow the user to limit the bandwidth of one or more network adapters. It does so by using iproute's tc command, but greatly simplifies its operation.

https://github.com/magnific0/wondershaper/blob/master/README.md

https://github.com/magnific0/wondershaper